# Is there a shortcut key for the cloak?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

The cloaking system is very useful for avoiding damage, but I can't seem to find a shortcut key to activate it. This makes using the cloak more difficult than it should be.

Is there a shortcut key for the cloak, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the main menu, go to:

- Options

  - Customize controls

All the keybindings are there.  Cloaking defaults to <kbd>c</kbd>.

Comment: They must have added that in a patch. Thanks for letting me know, or I never would have noticed.

Comment: In fact all hotkeys are (now?) displayed when you hover your mouse over the respective system

Answer (score 5):

You can always listen/watch for weapon/missile launch sounds/animations, hit the <kbd>Space</kbd> bar (it's your friend, use it and abuse it often) or middle mouse button (added in version 1.03.1) to pause, and toggle the Cloak and/or trigger it's respective hot key (added in version 1.03.1, customizable in the options menu).

As of this comment, I believe you can only use the number keys to select a weapon and fire (and to activate drones).

**<kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd>** keys, depending on how many weapon slots (e.g., weapon slot 1 = <kbd>1</kbd> key).

The **<kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd>** keys to your drone slot (as mentioned by Joe Wresching, and depending on the amount of drone slots your ship has).

Unfortunately, since you also use those same keys to select a dialog option, it can cause you to "accidentally" surrender. You can turn off these shortcuts off in Options.

In version 1.03.1 (added Dec. 21 2012), hot keys added for many actions (including cloaking), and is customizable from within the Options menu. Cloaking will also automatically cool down when your ship is out of danger and you can now also use the middle mouse button to pause the game.

Comment: +1 Considering a hot key doesn't exist, this seems like the most effective way to ensure a fast cloaking, which is what my real problem was.

Comment: Actually it's 1-4 and 5-7 no matter how many slots you have. If you have a ship with only three weapon slots, the first drone is still on 5.